# Java does not find class file

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface

i have problem running JAVA program from CLI:

[image: Java from CLI]

As you can see, i run `javac Main.java` to get Main.class file. And when trying to execute `java Main`, java can't find Main class. There is my class in Eclipse:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go one dir up `cd ..` and than `java stitching.Main`

Comment: Still nothing, "Error: Could not find or locate main class Main" running "java -cp Main.class Main"

Comment: @Justinas Sorry my fault. I have corrected my answer

Comment: @Justinas: the classpath (`-cp`) argument should contain the folders or JARs that contain the classes, not the classes themselves.  From the `src` folder, try `java -cp . stitching.Main`.

Answer (score 1):

You should first compile your class then run the the compiled class and not the sources. So from command line:

```
d:
cd programos/xampp/htdocs/im/OpenCV/src/stitching
javac Main.java
```

The above command will tell the java compiler to compile the sources of the `Main` class and generate a `.class` in bytecode which can be passed to the `java` process to be run:

```
java Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared your `Main` class to be in package `stitching`, what you should need to do is actually navigate to the folder *above* the root package (in the `bin` directory), then execute `java stitching/Main`